# Why is there radioactive decay?

Tags: particle-physics

I was explaining to a youngster that radioactive decay occurs because the randomly vibrating nuclear components occasionally align in such a way as to focus inertial forces onto a single outer particle with enough energy to eject it and that the odds of that alignment occurring define the half life. Is that anywhere near correct?

Comment: One immediate problem with that line of thought is that it doesn't explain why there are stable nuclei. I suppose we could just say that a stable nucleus has a *very* long half-life. FWIW, bismuth-209 has a half-life of approximately  $1.9×10^{19}$ years, and tellurium-128 is even more long-lived, with an estimated half-life of $7.7×10^{24}$ years. Both of those values were determined experimentally, but it's not easy to get precise results when the decays are so rare.

Comment: Another issue is that there's more to nucleon motion than random vibrations. Nucleon energy and momentum has structure, similar in many ways to the electron orbital structure which govern the chemical properties of atoms.

Answer (score 1):

No,it is not a correct summary. *Radioactive decay occurs because there exists a lower energy level than  the one the nucleus sits in, and there is a probability to decay to that, given by quantum mechanical calculations,* is the correct "summary".

All nuclei can be described by a [binding energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Nuclear_binding_energy_curve) per nucleon ( nucleons are protons and neutrons). This is a measured curve, and is calculated by finding the difference between the addition of free nucleon masses in units of energy ( special relativity)and the measured  mass of the nucleus, divided by the number of nucleons in that nucleus.

[image: bindener]

Then the possible nuclei  that a given nucleus can fragment into have to be taken into account, in order  to  find the  possible decay products, also conservation of quantum numbers, possible weak and electromagnetic transitions, in order  to find what the decay products will be.

Comment: Thank you. I find it easy to visualize the "randomly vibrating nuclear components occasionally aligning" of my imaginative BS. How do I, how does a nuclear physicist, visualize the achievement of a "lower energy level". I mean, what is the specific internal dynamic circumstance/configuration or sequence of events, that causes a nucleus to spit out an alpha particle?

Comment: why dont you read the introduction here :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_decay . A nuclear physicist has sat through so many courses that  the mathematics of energy levels and possible decays  are instinctive. The process  of decay is probabilistic, like throwing dice. The probability is weighted by the  quantum mechanical solutions in the interplay between attractive and repulsive nuclear forces.